# What are the limits placed on location gathering for apps running in the background on Android O devices?

Tags: android, android-location, fusedlocationproviderapi

I realize O is in developer preview at this point, but there are significant changes to background location gathering. What are they?

Answer (score 1):

The following points summarize the limits placed on location gathering on apps running on O devices:

- As a starting point, background apps will receive location updates only a few times each hour (the location update interval may be adjusted in the future based on system impact and feedback from developers).
- **Foreground apps are not affected by these limits.**
- These background limits apply to all apps running on an O device, **regardless of the target SDK**.
- Apps targeting O are further subject to [limits on services started in the background](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/background.html). For this reason, apps targeting O should not use `PendingIntent.getService()` when requesting location updates. Instead, they should use `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` and register a `BroadcastReceiver` in the manifest (apps targeting N or lower may use either `PendingIntent.getService()` or `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`).

Comment: Does anyone know value of `few times` each hour? How few is this?